# Como ler um arquivo .csv em C?

Tags: c, arquivo

Criei este código em C onde inseri as coordenadas de alguns pontos e com SVG desenhei esses pontos no espaço ligados por linhas. tudo salvo em um arquivo .html para ser executado no navegador.
É como um esquema de rotas onde quero calcular entre pontos.

A questão é: Até o momento inseri os pontos diretamente no meu código. Agora quero dar um up e ler os pontos X e Y de um outro arquivo que criei .csv, desenha-los em SVG e ligá-los através de linhas, assim como fiz até agora. E ao alterar o arquivo quero que o programa se atualize automaticamente.

Além da ajuda, dicas de otimização e melhoria também são bem vindos, pois sou inciante na programação.

O código a seguir está funcionando e é um exemplo do que quero fazer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MyFileName "MEUARQUIVOSVG.html"
#define MapSize 500

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *html = fopen(MyFileName,"w+");
    int coordenadas[5][2]={{50,50},{100,100},{150,320},{100,250},{400,300}};
    char string[1024];
    int i;

    fprintf(html,"<html> \n <body>\n");


    fprintf(html,"<h1>SVG em C</h1>");

    fprintf(html,"<svg width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\">\n",MapSize,MapSize);
    fprintf(html,"<rect width=\"%d\" height=\"%d\" style=\"fill:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:5;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)\" />\n",MapSize,MapSize);

    for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
        fprintf(html,"<circle cx=\"%d\" cy=\"%d\" r=\"3\" fill=\"blue\" />\n",coordenadas[i][0],coordenadas[i][1]);
        sprintf(string,"%s%d,%d ",string,coordenadas[i][0],coordenadas[i][1]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        fprintf(html,"<line x1=\"%d\" y1=\"%d\" x2=\"%d\" y2=\"%d\" style=\"stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2\" />\n", coordenadas[i+1][0],coordenadas[i+1][1], coordenadas[i][0],coordenadas[i][1]);
    }
    fprintf(html,"<polyline points=\"%s\" style=\"fill:white;stroke:red;stroke-width:1\"",string);
    fprintf(html,"</svg>\n");


    fprintf(html,"</body> \n </html>");

    fflush(html), fclose(html);
}
```

Desde já, obrigado!

Comment: o que você já tentou ? que problemas encontrou ? sua pergunta está muito genérica..

Comment: Já tentou abrir o seu arquivo `.csv` no `notepad` ou algum outro editor de texto, para ver como é a cara dele?